# jQuery on() change in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, onchange

Using jQuery 1.7.1, I'm trying to create an event handler for the change event on a dropdown. The dropdown is dynamically added to the DOM. Seems to work nicely on most browsers, but oh that kooky IE8 wants to be difficult. Is there a workaround? *Should* this work? I'm doing a lot of reading here and elsewhere and the input seems to be conflicting in many cases and the proposed solutions that I've found/tried haven't worked for me.

Can anyone clarify whether this should work in IE8 for `.state-seletor` dropdowns that are created on the fly?

```
$( document ).on( 'change', '.state-selector', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert( 'ON()' );
});
```

I'll keep poking around, but if anyone can clear this up before I lose my mind, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

At @Wertisdk's request below, here's my dropdown snippet:

```
<select name="data[Contractor][service_area_state]" class="state-selector">
  <option value="">Select a state...</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  ...
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE 2**

To @mblase75's point, maybe the method used to generate the dynamic dropdown matters. Essentially, I'm cloning an existing DOM node and emptying the value that was selected there. It should be noted that the `.additionalink a` is also generated dynamically. When you click an `.addtionallink a`, the template being cloned includes a new `.addtionallink a` node:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.additionallink a', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var copy = $( this ).closest( '.template' ).clone();

  // Massage the template copy's content and insert it
  // - Clear the value selected in the original dropdown
  // - Clear the list of counties loaded based on the original dropdown selection
  $( '.state-selector', copy ).val( $( '.state-selector option:first', copy ).val() );
  $( '.counties', copy ).empty();
  $( this ).closest( '.template' ).after( copy );
});
```

**UPDATE 3**

Here's a similar [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc4RS/). It's *almost* my code, but there's one key difference that might be all the difference. This fiddle uses `.append()` to insert new content based on the state selection. My code uses the `.load()` method. Otherwise, it's all the same.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the html, the jQuery is going to interact with? 
It might be specific to the html element you are targeting.

Comment: I am looking forward to this answer. I have the same problem.

Comment: @Wertisdk, I've updated my question above. I'm not sure how helpful it is, but ask and you shall receive (sometimes). :-)

Comment: I'm curious: what's the benefit of adding `e.preventDefault()` to a `change` handler?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/67B2R/3/ -- works fine with this dynamically-created select element in IE8 for me.

Comment: Curiously, Why are you using (document).change?  why not ('select') on change?  You're applying the change function to the entire document?

Comment: @Downpour046 You may want to read up about the `.on()` function. He is binding to the document so it will catch the bubbles of dynamically created elements matching his selector (`'.state-selector'`)
@RobWilkerson I don't see anything inherently wrong with this code, at least not the binding. Can we get a live page/jsFiddle of your code?

Comment: @Chad, thanks for the info, I'm aware of how the .on() function works, I just thought it was odd to use document as the call vs a parent or something of that nature.  Was just wondering-   I tried mblase's fiddle in IE8 and it worked for me too.

Comment: @Chad, yeah, let me put something together. If I'm not losing my mind, then maybe I have a conflict somewhere that IE8 isn't reporting to me.

Comment: @RobWilkerson That would be my guess since mblase75's fiddle works fine for others in IE.

Comment: @Chad, fiddle linked in an update to the question. The fiddle works, but I had to replace a `.load()` call that populates dynamic content with a `.append()` call because of the cross domain fun. Would using `.load()` have that kind of impact?

Comment: Check that. It doesn't work. In my frustration, I just flipped over to the fiddle in safari. Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the magic word here is `.clone()`, you may be running into this bug which has already been fixed in the 1.7.2 beta: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11076

Comment: The ticket doesn't indicate that it's specific to IE8 which is definitely what I'm seeing. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yessuh, it surely does appear to. Strange that the bug IE8-specific (at least for me). I'll do a bit more testing, but early signs are good.

Comment: Yep, there were two `.clone()` bugs, and this was the second: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10878

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for your help, both here and fixing the bugs. :-)